# How to get a float transition on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to make a float transition on Xamarin Forms, something like this:

[image]

I got the reference from this library for swift https://github.com/Kawoou/KWDrawerController

Additionally I need to make a menu behind the main view, one for the right and one different for the left side.

I'll be glad to know where can I start or something. Thank you folks.